# Datagrid contents with UI Automation and .net

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, ui-automation

I'm having some trouble reading the contents of a Datagrid in an external application using UI Automation and could use some pointers. Here's what I have so far:

```
int id = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Book")[0].Id;
AutomationElement desktop = AutomationElement.RootElement;

AutomationElement bw = desktop.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, id));

AutomationElement datagrid = bw.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "lv"));

AutomationElementCollection lines = datagrid.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.DataItem));

AutomationElementCollection items = lines[1].FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Custom));

GridItemPattern pattern = items[1].GetCurrentPattern(GridItemPattern.Pattern) as GridItemPattern;
TableItemPattern tablePattern = items[1].GetCurrentPattern(TableItemPattern.Pattern) as TableItemPattern;
```

This works in as much as I can access the column ids and row ids from the GridItemPattern and TableItemPattern but how do I access the value that is in that specific cell? Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out, it requires the use of CacheRequest to request the Name property on the AutomationElement. Here's the final code:

```
var cacheRequest = new CacheRequest
{
    AutomationElementMode = AutomationElementMode.None,
    TreeFilter = Automation.RawViewCondition
};

cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.NameProperty);
cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty);

cacheRequest.Push();

var targetText = loginLinesDetails[i].FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "TextBlock"));

cacheRequest.Pop();

var myString = targetText.Cached.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [ValuePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.valuepattern.aspx) for it. Just like that:

```
ValuePattern pattern = items[0].GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern) as ValuePattern;
string value = pattern.Current.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I get a "Unsupported Pattern" exception when trying to grab the Value Pattern. The UISpy only shows GridItem and TableItem as valid patterns. Any other ideas? :)

Comment: That's sad =( In my test application the value displayed in the cell was also contained in the Name field of cell's AutomationElementInformation element (`items[1].Current.Name` for your sample)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the AutomationElement classes but I have used [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) to automate some simple windows stuff in the past (find a dialog, click a button, etc) and it was cake. You might consider it. The download contains a .dll you can reference from a .Net solution.

I'm not sure if the external app is a WinForm grid or not but here is an ASP.Net grid example: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/13709-how-to-get-the-contents-of-datagrid-control/

Then again, if you are scraping the info from the web I would recommend [WatiN](http://watin.org/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: Hey, I've used AutoIT quite alot in the past and a bit of the AutoITX library but I can't even see the datagrid in the external app with its Window Info app. I think it's a WPF application with every control in a wrapper. The reason I wanted to use AutomationElement was because I can see the DataGrid with the UISpy so I assumed it would be possible to pull the values, it's looking as though that's not the case though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using RawViewWalker on a element to get raw values (On controlview you might not be able to get few properties)

Comment: is this intended as a comment on MoMo's answer?