# Iterate over items for databounded WPF listview

Tags: wpf, listview

i am developing an application that contains many listviews, each listview is bounded to an ObservableCollection, and each observable collection holds different custom object type.

I need a method that takes my listview as a parameter (regardless what type of objects it holds), and iterates over its items and cells to write the data to an excel file.

i could get the ListViewItem from the ItemContainerGenerator, but i couldn't iterate over the columns. also i tried to get the GridViewRowPresenter but i got nothing, because i reached a point that i have to unbox my object to a specific datatype.

Comment: Why not iterating over your ObservableCollection? This should be much easier.

Comment: when I iterate on the collection I have to cast to known type

Comment: the method cannot know what is the type of object that is held by the collection.

Comment: And you think you can avoid casting by iterating over ListViewItems?  I'm afraid that you can't.

Comment: i think so because i done this from 4 years ago,but unfortunately i can't remember how. may be i used ICollectionViewSource, but what after?. i can't remember

Comment: @NohaAmer, `IEditableCollectionView` perhaps?  `ItemsControl.Items` (`ItemCollection`) has a whole host of interesting representations.

Answer (score 0):

In the most trivial model, you could use `ListView.Items.SourceCollection` combined with `Column.DisplayMemberPath` to get a reference to the databound object and the property you are supposed to print.

```
ListView lv = /* magically got a reference to the listview */;
var collection = lv.Items.SourceCollection;
var columns = ((GridView)lv.View).Columns;

// I am assuming you already have an excel writer
// write the headers
excelWriter.StartRow();
foreach (var header in columns)
{
    excelWriter.WriteCell(header.Header);
}
excelWriter.EndRow();

// get propertyinfo
// this will fail if there are no items in the collection
var tDataItem = collection.First().GetType();
// this will fail for anything but the most simple bindings
var piColumns = columns.Select(c => tDataItem.GetProperty(((Binding)c.DisplayMemberBinding).Path));

// start data
foreach (var dataitem in collection)
{
    excelWriter.StartRow();
    foreach (var pi in piColumns)
    {
        var propValue = pi.GetValue(dataItem, null);
        // given that this is of type object, you will probably have to format this
        excelWriter.WriteCell(propValue);
    }
    excelWriter.EndRow();
}
```

The other model you could use is to [try and read the cell values from the automation interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547537/datagrid-contents-with-ui-automation-and-net).  I know `DataGrid` supports automation, but I am not certain of `GridView`.